# Platform independent reliable password hashing on Android, IOS and Browser with cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hash

I have created a cordova application that sends a login request to an external api using a username and password. I want to hash the password reliably before passing it to the api, but have not found a good way to hash it platform independent. I tried the plugins cordova-plugin-password-crypto and cordova-plugin-minisodium but both seem to support only Android and IOS.

Why do these implementations support only Android and IOS and is there an alternative available for Android, IOS and Browser?

Comment: Use a PHP script to hash and return the result using an appropriate API (example: volley(if cordova doesn't allow the usage of PHP))

Comment: Too bad it requires the use of PHP, I was looking for a pure js solution. Thanks for the help though!